# Are SiC Mosfets better than Si Mosfets for Solar Charger in max 550V Range

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

The charger needs to handle the solar array's output of max 550V, but also efficiently handle lower voltages as weather/etc conditions degrade -- down to roughly 150V. It needs to handle between 15 - 50A. Thats quite the wide range of voltages and current, but is the nature of this particular solar setup. Efficient power conversion is of prime importance. I'll be using an MPPT type algorithm at the MCU with 5V output to the gate driver. PWM frequency will likely depend on the Fet used -- I'm assuming >50KHz. Output power to the batteries will be approx. 120V. Price isn't too much of a concern, hard costs need to come in at under $100USD per unit (but much less is preferable).

One of the options I'm currently looking at is [Wolfspeed's 650V SiC Mosfet](https://www.wolfspeed.com/power/products/sic-mosfets/650v-silicon-carbide-mosfets).

And, on the Si Mosfet side: [OnSemi's Super Junction Mosfet](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discretes-drivers/mosfets/fcp125n65s3).

From what I've read, SiC Mosfets really outperform Si in high power applications and in high frequency PWM drivers. It seems their current market value is in converting much higher voltages, up to 1200V. Those power levels are above the scope of my *lowly* project of only 550V.

My question is: Are SiC Mosfets an appropriate technology to incorporate into <=550V power switching? Will I gain power conversion efficiencies with them compared to other more standard Si Fets in that power range? Or, do those efficiencies deteriorate at lower voltages -- where Si Mosfets would do just as well?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get below US$100 per unit, especially not if you're using SiC. The 50 A requirement also means you'll need a really beefy inductor, and that won't come cheap either. I'd estimate this project would probably cost about $500 per unit, but wouldn't be surprised if it goes higher than that.

Comment: If you can afford it, SiC will outperform Si if you select and use it properly, taking advantage of its strengths. It will be much more expensive though.

Comment: depends... SiC is where Si was in the 1960, the production is now ramping up and is almost doubling each year and this will drive the cost down. I spend £350 on a 6switch inverter 3years ago but I can make that out of suitably rated discretes for £80 using Wolfspeeds 4th Gen devices (650V, 60A) in TO-263-HV package. While SiC will be more expensive the systematic wins are huge... heatsinking and cooling is reduced so sometimes it is worth driving cost into one area for it to benefit elsewhere( weight volume other system needs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My question is: Are SiC Mosfets an appropriate technology to
> incorporate into <=550V power switching? Will I gain power conversion
> efficiencies with them compared to other more standard Si Fets in that
> power range? Or, do those efficiencies deteriorate at lower voltages
> -- where Si Mosfets would do just as well?*

Comparing two devices in the links (Si = [FCP125N65S3](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fcp125n65s3-d.pdf) and the [Cree C3M0120065K](https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/2004/product/465/c3m0120065k.pdf)), they both have about the same on resistance, max voltage and max current. However, the MOSFET will be slightly more efficient at around 50 kHz but, at speeds probably in excess of 200 kHz the SiC will probably be better due to its lower gate-source capacitance.

The Cree (SiC) will require a more sophisticated protection regime to avoid thermal runaway compared to the regular Si device because most SiCs don't avoid this even in switching applications. Si MOSFETs do avoid this problem rather well.

The gate drive voltages for SiC are about 150% higher than regular Si too. This both causes losses and slows things down a little bit and, designing a SiC gate driver needs a little more thought compared to Si. However, there's still a good chance that SiC will be significantly faster than Si and *should* be operated at a higher speed.

If the bulk diode is at all utilized for any form of flyback management then the SiC will be better because it has a faster reverse recovery time of 15 ns compared to 339 ns for the silicon but, the diode power losses are far more significant in the SiC compared to the Si.

<sub>Remember, this is a quick data sheet-to-data sheet side by side comparison. A true comparison only ever happens when you compare a circuit against another circuit because some parameters will be more important than others.</sub>

Comment: Just as another note, the energy rated output capacitance of SiC is significantly less than Si for similar RDSon, and that can make a difference in efficiency as well.

Comment: @JohnD very good point. Actually, the Si linked has 62 pF and the SiC linked has 57 pF and that surprised me a little i.e. both being about the same at 400 volts!

Comment: That surprises me too! Usually SiC is substantially lower.

Comment: I don't quite understand the thermal runaway argument. Wouldn't it be the other way around, if you look at the temperature dependence of the on-resistance?

Comment: In switching applications, standard MOSFETs regulate their temperature but most SiC devices still have thermal runaway problems at all but the highest gate drive voltages. Check figure 7 in Cree data sheet and compare it with fig 2 in the other data sheet.

Comment: But remember this is just me comparing A against B so shouldn’t be taken as a general rule.

Comment: Comparing these two would swing things towards the Si. If you compare against their 4th gen the Rds_on is 20-30mR and thus the conduction losses are significantly reduced. Also what is lost in the comparison in switching losses as these are typically not shown for Si devices. For an appropriately driven SiC device (fast edge, high current) the switching losses are tiny producing a double win via conduction and switching.  Compare against this - https://www.st.com/en/power-transistors/scth100n65g2-7ag.html this uses Cree 4th gen ingot's since Cree do not list their 4th gen yet

Comment: @JonRB the OP listed the devices so I was trying to keep the comparison in context of the question.

Comment: @Andyaka yup I get that, was just adding context here. Personally I would not have picked that particular SiC device the OP down-selected, it's only benefit would be in driving switching frequency (shrink magnetics) as the conduction losses are comparable. What I would do is see what budget I could afford to pick lower Rdson SiC and win systematically. If the OP main constraint is cost and savings elsewhere cannot help pick a better SiC then yes the Si will win with these constraints.

Comment: @JonRB OK, context is good! It's a many sided problem and my disclaimer is that you should analyse A vs B when you have a target application/circuit.

Comment: @JonRB, Thank you for posting a link to St's SiC. With its lower Rds_on it does seem it will have less switching losses than 3rd gen. Although I agree with Andyaka, its good to at least post options outside the strict bounds of the questions: thats how we discover. In my context, I think I will be forced toward using OnSemi's Si because its performance is rather good and at a far lower cost point. Although, I do wish I could move forward on SiC technology. We're just not quite yet at the cost/benefit point for my particular market.